# How do you condense the values in a T-SQL pivot into a JSON?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have a table in SQL Server of the form:

| date | userId | sessionStartTime | SessionEndTime | nClicks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 0 | 9:00:00 | 9:15:10 | 4 |
| 2020-01-01 | 0 | 9:33:00 | 10:05:05 | 2 |
| 2020-01-01 | 2 | 9:05:20 | 9:25:55 | 9 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I'm looking to `PIVOT` it by `userId` and `date` and get something that consolidates the other columns as a JSON array. The output is envisioned to look like:

| date | userId | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 0 | `[{'sessionStartTime':9:00:00, 'SessionEndTime':9:15:10, 'nClicks':4}, {'sessionStartTime':9:33:00, 'SessionEndTime':10:05:05, 'nClicks':2}]` |
| 2020-01-01 | 2 | `[{'sessionStartTime':9:05:20, 'SessionEndTime':9:25:55, 'nClicks':9}]` |
| ... | ... | ... |

Any ideas on how you could achieve this in SQL (T-SQL)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not support `JSON_AGG`, which would have simplified things.

[@Zhorov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70256841/14868997) requires a self-join, but this can actually be done with a single scan of the table and with normal aggregation, using `STRING_AGG`:

```sql
SELECT
  [date],
  [userId],
  STRING_AGG(N'[' + [data] + N']', N',')
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT [sessionStartTime], [SessionEndTime], [nClicks]
   FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
) j (data)
GROUP BY
  [date],
  [userId];
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=36fba498093fa05babf9c092633d93ce)

Comment: Thank you; this worked and was fast.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate the JSON content for each distinct combination of `[date]` and `[userId]`:

Table:

```
SELECT *
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES
   ('2020-01-01', 0, '9:00:00', '9:15:10', 4),
   ('2020-01-01', 0, '9:33:00', '10:05:05', 2),
   ('2020-01-01', 2, '9:05:20', '9:25:55', 9)
) v ([date], [userId], [sessionStartTime], [SessionEndTime], [nClicks])
```

T-SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [date], [userId], [data]
FROM Data d
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT [sessionStartTime], [SessionEndTime], [nClicks]
   FROM Data 
   WHERE d.[date] = [date] AND d.[userId] = [userId]
   FOR JSON PATH
) j (data)
```

Result:

| date | userId | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 0 | [{"sessionStartTime":"9:00:00","SessionEndTime":"9:15:10","nClicks":4},{"sessionStartTime":"9:33:00","SessionEndTime":"10:05:05","nClicks":2}] |
| 2020-01-01 | 2 | [{"sessionStartTime":"9:05:20","SessionEndTime":"9:25:55","nClicks":9}] |

Comment: Good answer. This is actually possible without a self-join, using `STRING_AGG`