# Transform columns in Array from JSON

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following data.

| ID | DESCRIPTION | COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 | COLUMN3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TESTE1 | X1 | X2 | X3 |
| 2 | TESTE2 | X1 | X2 | X3 |
| 3 | TESTE3 | X1 | X2 | X3 |
| 4 | TESTE4 | X1 | X2 | X3 |
| 5 | TESTE5 | X1 | X2 | X3 |

I need to turn this into :

```
{
  "id":1,
  "description": "TESTE1",
  "columns": [
         "X1",
         "X2",
         "X3"
  ]
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: It doesn't matter what language you write it in, you need to do you own research, and attempt before asking for help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you condense the values in a T-SQL pivot into a JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70256658/how-do-you-condense-the-values-in-a-t-sql-pivot-into-a-json)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way.
Using string_agg & json_query for the string array.

> ```
> select json
> from
> (
>     select t.id, t.description
>     , json_query(ca.column_array, '$') columns
>     from your_table t
>     cross apply (
>         select concat('["', string_agg([col],'","'), '"]')
>         from (values 
>          (column1), 
>          (column2), 
>          (column3)) c(col)
>     ) ca(column_array)
>     order by t.id
>     for json path
> ) q(json)
> ```

And another way.
Using json_modify for the string array.

> ```
> select json
> from
> (
>     select id, description,
>       json_modify(
>         json_modify(
>           json_modify('[]', 
>             'append $', column1),
>             'append $', column2), 
>             'append $', column3) as columns
>     from your_table
>     order by id
>     for json path
> ) q(json);
> ```

| json |
| --- |
| [{"id":1,"description":"TESTE1","columns":["X1","X2","X3"]},{"id":2,"description":"TESTE2","columns":["X1","X2","X3"]},{"id":3,"description":"TESTE3","columns":["X1","X2","X3"]},{"id":4,"description":"TESTE4","columns":["X1","X2","X3"]},{"id":5,"description":"TESTE5","columns":["X1","X2","X3"]}] |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=834cf9bab1beb892f80ca3fa588cc02d)*